# Getting error when building sonar in Eclipse(Indigo) Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar

Tags: java

```
I am using **sonarqube-5.2** and the plugins are :- 

sonar-web-plugin-2.4.jar   
sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar  
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar  
sonar-pmd-plugin-2.6.jar  
sonar-java-plugin-3.6.jar  
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar  
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar  
sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar  

**I am getting the error :-** 

**Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project webchannel-core-multimodule: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**

[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905  
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy  
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar  
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar  
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar  
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar  
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar  
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/u37171/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar  
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1  
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Do I need to upgrade my sonar(now using 5.2) or to use other plugins ?

Could any one please help me on this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try downgrading the version of sonar-maven-plugin to 3.0.2 as per http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Seems that the plugin version that you are using is built using JDK8 and hence you get the major.minor version mismatch.